# Rsync + public key authentication security

Tags: rsync, ssh-keys

I have read several articles how to automatically backup files with Rsync and public key authentication. All of them are very similar. I just finished setting up everything and everything works fine but... I just found an article which says it's not secure. I did the following:

1. On backup server I generated public and private keys.
2. I copied public key to the remote (original) servers directory: `/var/sites/.ssh` (file `authorized_keys`). The directory is owned by `"user12"`
3. I added the following to the authorized_keys file: `from="BACKUP.SERVERS.IP.ADDRESS",command="/root/validate_rsync"`
4. I created a file /root/validate_rsync with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND >> /var/log/synchronize-log.log
   case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
   *\&*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\;*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\(*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\{*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\<*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\>*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\`*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   *\|*)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   rsync\ --server*) 
   $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
   ;;
   *)
   echo "Rejected"
   ;;
   esac
   ```

I run the rsync command:

```
rsync -avzp --del -e "ssh -p 2211" user12@ORIGINAL.SERVERS.IP:/var/sites/photos/ /var/sites/sync/photos
```

I got error message: permission problems with file `/root/validate_rsync`. I moved the file `/root/validate_rsync` to `/var/sites/validate_rsync` and chowned it to user12:user12

Now synchronization works. But I found an article which says it's insecure:

*1- the validate_rsync command itself should not be owned nor writeable by
the userid that executes the rsync command.   Otherwise, rsync can be used
to overwrite the validation script with another script that doesn't
validate, or even execute arbitrary commands.*

*2- similarly, the authorized-keys file should not be owned or writeable by
the rsync user, otherwise rsync can be used to overwrite that file, with
one that removes the requirement to run validate-rsync, or with one that
runs some other command instead.*

[Source](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2014-April/029419.html)

What can I do? If `validate_rsync` is owned by root, the synchronization does not start because `user12` can't access `root`'s files. If `authorized-keys` file will be owned by another user I will not be able to login with username `user12`.

**My questions:**

1. Where should I put validate_rsync and authorized-keys files, in which directory? What permissions and ownerships should they have?
2. Is there some way how to tell to the `validate_rsync` file to allow to synchronize only 2 folders: `/var/sites/photos/`, `/var/sites/photos2/`

Comment: https://github.com/scponly/scponly

Comment: I don't see why you need a validate-sync script anyway. If you are using rsync as a backup, you could just use a forced command that specifies rsync --server    (Possibly with some further options too)

Comment: @CameronKerr, although not really needed, it gives you more flexibility if you want to allow a rsync command with different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those security concerns are right. So, to answer your first question: to make it work as you like, you should put validate_rsync in a directory where `user12` has execute permission, but not write. The very same `validate_rsync` file should have read and execute permissions for the user, but of course not write. The issue here is that `/root` by default is accessible only by `root` user, you need a path where each directory has execute permission for `user12`. For example, you could copy `validate_rsync` to `/usr/local/bin` and make it owned by `root`. As long as `user12` can execute and read, it's OK.

You don't need to protect your `authorized_keys` file. It would be better to force `user12` to run a command by configuration, putting in `sshd_config` the following:

```
Match user user12
  ForceCommand /usr/local/bin/validate_rsync
```

I think this solution is better than tinkering with authorized_keys.

Also, in your `validate_rsync` I would quote `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` (safer), and I would change your `case` sentence to check the validty of the command for a regular expression using `grep`; easier, more compact and more powerful:

```
echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" >> /var/log/synchronize-log.log
if echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" | grep -qE '[&;<>`|]'; then
  echo Rejected
elif [[ "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:0:14}" == "rsync --server" ]]; then
  $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
else
  echo Rejected
fi
```

To answer your second question, as you are logging the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND, you can run a test with the directories you want to consider and then examine the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND you are getting. Then you could make `validate_rsync` to validate just that command.

Comment: Sorry, that is the PS, these are alternative solutions that I put in previous edits of the answer, but I suggest you use the solution in the answer instead: putting `Match user` in `sshd_config`. Sorry, the response was a bit confusing, I'm going to delete the PS.

Comment: 1. I copied file `validate_rsync` to `/usr/local/validate_rsync`. It's owned by root and permissions 754. Can't synchronize - `permission denied`. 2. Your first solution of authorized_keys was better. Unfortunately, I didn't copy it. I also need to login as `user12` with username and password to upload files vis sftp to `/var/sites/`. If I add `ForceCommand`, I need to create another user for this purpose, but all uploaded files then will be owned by this user, not by `user12`. Everything too complicated.

Comment: 1. Which group? Why not permissions 755? 2. Why do you think authorized_keys solution was better? It was more complicated and less safe, it didn't have any benefit. You don't need to use sftp to upload files, rsync can be used for that as well.

Comment: 755 for `validate_rsync` solved permission problem. I can't upload files from my home computer (windows) to the server (debian) using rsync. Then I need a special software. It's much easier using sftp. I think I will leave authorized_keys file where is it. This file contains line from="BACKUP_SERVER_IP". I changed line `rsync\ --server*)` to `rsync\ --server\ --sender\ -vlogDtprze.iLsf\ .\ /var/sites/photos/*)`. Actually, I don't understand how someone else using `rsync` command could change `authorized_keys file. Maybe I need to open a new question. We have too many comments and I it will be

Comment: You could use `rsync` to replace your `authorized_keys` file if you have permissions on it *and* if you are not restricting which paths to synchronize in `validate_rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

To protect the `authorized_keys` file, I came across this solution: https://superuser.com/questions/852434/how-to-protect-authorized-keys-file

> It's pretty common to simply remove write-access to that file if
>   you're not planning to change it often.

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

> Now, of course, that write access could be added back in by a
>   malicious script, so you need to set the file and its parent directory
>   to be immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh
```